# Angular nested GETs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an interesting situation where I am getting a list of ids from one GET request and then I want to grab the first one and do another GET request to get an image url for that object. Unfortunately there are times when the ID returned from the first GET request is not valid and we need to then check the next ID. I am currently attempting some recursive callback way of doing this but that is not doing what I want and I'm simply getting back no results due to Angular's asynchronous nature.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
app.controller('gr_menu', function($scope, grAPI, flashManager, catalogAPI) {
$scope.reports = [];

grAPI.ReportList().then(
  function(success) {
    success.data.forEach(function(report) {
      if(report.live) {
        $scope.reports.concat({'id': report.id, 'title': report.game, 'imgUrl': getReportData(report)});
      }
    });
  },
  function(error) {
    flashManager.flashMessage('Danger', 'Failed to load game reports: '+error);
  });

function getReportData(report) {
  catalogAPI.SearchGame(report.game, [{"json.offerType":"Base Game"}])
    .then(function(success){
      var i = 0;
      return checkOfferID(success.data.result[i].offerId, function (result) {
        i++;
        console.log(result)

        if (result != false) {
          return checkOfferID(success.data.result[i].offerType);
        } else {
          return result;
        }
      });
    });
}

function checkOfferID(offerID) {
  Origin.games.catalogInfo(offerID)
    .then(function (catData) {
      return catData.customAttributes.imageServer + catData.localizableAttributes.packArtLarge;
    }, function (catErr) {
      return false;
    });
  }
});
```

So it's actually 3 GET requests deep. First is to get a list of our "reports" and then from there get the IDs of the games indicated in those reports, and then from there get the images.

I am getting nothing from that console.log so perhaps I'm misunderstanding how that callback should work. I am still trying to familiarize myself with working with Angular and callbacks. I would have implemented this via a simple for loop and break if it were python.

Comment: Your `getReportData` isn't returning anything. Also you are not recursively calling anything, you are just calling `checkOfferId()` for the first and second elements. You should look into how promises work.

Comment: Is it possible to join all that data on the server, so you'll do one request from the client? In your case you're doing ~ (1 + n*2) requests, which is not a best practice.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over these apis except the very first one. Or I would definitely go that route rather than making nested calls.

Comment: I am semi-familiar with promises. However I am still learning how to work with them and angular so some guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't really make sense of your code (I'm also getting my first steps with angularJS) but I think you want something like the following "app.js" (simple example using a module with a controller and a service):

```
angular.module('testApp', [])
  .controller('TestCtrl', ['$log','TestService',
      function($log, TestService) {
        var self = this;
        TestService.getUserList().then(function (ld) {
          TestService.getUserInfo().then(function(ud){
            //$log.log(ud.data.args.url);
            self.photo_url = ud.data.args.url;
          })
        });
  }])
  .factory('TestService', ['$log', '$http', function($log, $http) {
    return {
      getUserList: function() {
        return $http.get('https://httpbin.org/get?list=[{id:1,%20name:%20%22jhon%22},{id:2,%20name:%22Lewis%22}]')
      },
      getUserInfo: function() {
        return $http.get('https://httpbin.org/get?id=1&name=jhon&url=https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/346173670fc42829e26d7965cbc5c3e0')
     }
    };
  }]);
```

Then you can bind "photo_url" value to the HTML, something like (index.html):

```
<html ng-app="testApp">
    <body ng-controller="TestCtrl as testCtrl">
      <img ng-src='{{testCtrl.photo_url}}' alt="something kwel"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.js">
        </script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Hope to have understood what you wanted, and hope this helps you as well.

NOTE: Tested with mocked urls from http bin.

Comment: you can't return `photo_url` it is being retrieved asynchronously. The service method needs to return a promise

Comment: yeah, really sorry about that, now I have tested it. I got that part wrong, thanks for the comment it helped me understand it! =D